# How do you enable the gnome-remote-desktop service from the command line?

Tags: amazon-ec2, gnome

I am running an EC2 instance on AWS running RockyOS. The system boots with gnome running, but I can not access the gnome session, so I can not run the settings apps to enable the remote desktop sharing.

Is there anyway to configure the remote screen sharing password and enable the remote desktop sharing service via the command line?

I know I can install xvnc, but I would rather just be able to access the main gnome session.

Answer (score 1):

I found this gist that enables VNC + RDP. I personally had trouble with writing password in `secret-tool` due locked `gnome-keyring` but it's still good inspiration:

https://gist.github.com/greyltc/7085bff8f2e728b60077b81329019828